# Read numbers from file in java

Tags: java

I'm sorry for the other post here is my code: It works, it prints the text file but i don't know how to separate the first row from the others. I mean that I want to save the values from the first row into 2 variables and then process the remaining lines.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;


public class read {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        String scan;
        FileReader file = new FileReader("C:\\Users\\W7\\workspace\\SimpleGraph(01-10-13)\\numbers.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(file);

        while((scan = br.readLine()) != null)
                {
            System.out.println(scan);
                }
        br.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, read the first line, before the loop, then start the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Just read the first line separated and then iterate over the rest of the file.
EDIT:
You can split your String into an array and read your Integers like this:

```
String scan;
FileReader file = new FileReader("C:\\Users\\W7\\workspace\\SimpleGraph(01-10-13)\\numbers.txt");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(file);
String first = br.readLine();
if ( null != first) {
    System.out.println("First is: " + first);
    String[] numberStrings = first.split(" ");
    int[] numbers = new int[numberStrings.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(numberStrings[i]);
        System.out.println("Number " + i + " is " + numbers[i]);
    }
    while((scan = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(scan);
    }
}
br.close();
```

Comment: This works but now first is a string containing 2 numbers. For example: 2 3. How do i split this string and put each number in a variable?

Comment: I've updated my answer. You can access your numbers with numbers[0] and numbers[1]

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
            public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            String scan;
            FileReader file = new FileReader("C:\\Users\\W7\\workspace\\SimpleGraph(01-10-13)\\numbers.txt");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(file);
            boolean isFirstLine = true;
            int forstNo = 0;
            while ((scan = br.readLine()) != null) {
                if(isFirstLine){
                    forstNo = Integer.parseInt(scan);
                    isFirstLine = false;
                }

                System.out.println(scan);
            }
            br.close();
            System.out.println("first no "+forstNo);
        }
```